# apache mod_rewrite is not resolving OK

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache server (80 port) running ok as a Reverse proxy of local webserver (82 port) and mod_rewrite without any .htaccess files.

I can navigate OK to http://localhost/CONTACT.PRO, it shows me website located on local web server at http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/CONTACT.PRO

The problem is trying to create friendly URLs using mod_rewrite, it shows me an error from local webserver (not apache error), so I guess I am not sending the correct URL to local webserver (82 port)

Can you please help me to figure out what happens?

In Apache folder, I only have main / original httpd.conf with enable "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" and including "conf/extra/ABC.conf" where I put my config:

```
NameVirtualHost *
ExtendedStatus On

<virtualHost *>

ServerName www.ABC.com
ServerAlias 192.168.1.250
ServerAlias localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@ABC.com
DirectoryIndex index.htm
ProxyPass /cgi-vel/web/  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/ 
keepalive=on  
ProxyPass /  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/ keepalive=on  
ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/ keepalive=on 
ProxyPreserveHost On
ErrorLog "logs/test_web_error.log"
CustomLog "logs/test_web-access.log" combined 

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact$ /CONTACTAR.PRO?W-IDIOMA=EN [P]
RewriteRule ^item$   /ITEM.PRO
RewriteRule ^special /SALE.PRO?_sale=109

</virtualHost>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, ProxyPass is evaluated before RewriteEngine, so RewriteEngine never sees your URL.
Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003358/apache-rewrite-then-proxy-pass

You have to tell RewriteEngine to pass the URL back to the URL handler by adding [PT]

Comment: thank you but is not working [L,PT] or [PT] :-(

Comment: Just a wild guess: have you tried putting your rewrite-rules above the proxypass rules?

Comment: it is not working :-(

Comment: Last resort: keep the proxypassreverse rules and replace the proxypass rules with RewriteRules that do the proxying (i.e. RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/$1 [P])

Comment: thank you very much for taking care and trying to help! I am getting this 

    **Request-URI Too Large**
    The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.